# using ffmpeg for live streaming MPEG-TS with windows media services

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming

I'm trying to live stream MPEG-TS source to Windows Media service.
I found how to live stream using RTMP with this code:

```
ffmpeg -y -f mpegts -i udp://@:1234 -re -vcodec libx264 -maxrate 700k
-r 25 -s 640x360 -deinterlace -acodec libvo_aacenc -ab 64k -ac 1 -ar 44100 -f flv "rtmp://rtmp1.youtube.com/videolive?sparams=<STREAM PARAMETERS HERE>"
```

- How can I convert it to support WM9/VC1 format?
- Does ffmpeg support pulling of the stream or only pushing to Windows Media services?

Comment: Are you hoping to encode to WM9/VC1 using FFmpeg? FFmpeg can't do that (it can decode this codec but not encode it).

Comment: Thank you, now everything comes clear.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Media Service can receive data only from Windows Media Encoder.
It can't work with RTMP which its flash technology.
if your input stream is a file or a capture device than you can use "Windows Live Media Encoder".

Comment: I know that VLC can encode video to Windows Media service, but I was also trying to do it with ffmpeg.